# New pubspec Flutter plugin declaration causes MissingPluginException

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, dart

**Edit 3-4-2019**

After doing some more research i found out that when generating a new plugin with the `flutter create --org com.example --template=plugin hello` command, it still uses the old pubspec declaration format. If we however change the old format to the new format, it gives the same error as I encounterd.

**Original post**

[I'm working on a Flutter plugin](https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/flutter_ble_peripheral), and before migrating my plugin to the Flutter v2 embedding I had the following declaration in my pubspec:

```
flutter:
  plugin:
    packageAndroid: dev.steenbakker.flutter_ble_peripheral
    pluginClass: FlutterBlePeripheralPlugin
```

However, in [the guide provided by flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) it is suggested to use the new type of declaration, which separates the different platforms as follows:

```
flutter:
  plugin:
    platform:
      ios:
        pluginClass: FlutterBlePeripheralPlugin
      android:
        package: dev.steenbakker.flutter_ble_peripheral
        pluginClass: FlutterBlePeripheralPlugin
```

However, after doing this, I get the following error every time I want to execute something from the library:

```
2020-04-01 13:54:03.134943+0200 Runner[1328:1208976] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method start on channel dev.steenbakker.flutter_ble_peripheral/ble_state)
#0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      FlutterBlePeripheral.start (package:flutter_ble_peripheral/flutter_ble_peripheral.dart:48:26)
#2      _MyAppState.startBroadcast (package:flutter_ble_peripheral_example/main.dart:53:19)
#3      _MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_ble_peripheral_example/main.dart:65:32)
```

I have fully implemented the new embedding on android as follows:

```
/** FlutterBlePeripheralPlugin */
class FlutterBlePeripheralPlugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, EventChannel.StreamHandler {

  private var applicationContext: Context? = null
  private var methodChannel: MethodChannel? = null
  private var eventChannel: EventChannel? = null
  private var peripheral: Peripheral? = null
  private var eventSink: EventChannel.EventSink? = null
  private var advertiseCallback: (Boolean) -> Unit = { isAdvertising ->
    eventSink?.success(isAdvertising)
  }

/** Plugin registration embedding v1 */
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun registerWith(registrar: PluginRegistry.Registrar) {
     FlutterBlePeripheralPlugin().onAttachedToEngine(registrar.context(), registrar.messenger())
    }
  }

/** Plugin registration embedding v2 */
  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
  onAttachedToEngine(flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext, flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger)
  methodChannel!!.setMethodCallHandler(this)
  eventChannel!!.setStreamHandler(this)
  peripheral = Peripheral()
  peripheral!!.init(flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext)
}

  private fun onAttachedToEngine(applicationContext: Context, messenger: BinaryMessenger) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext
    methodChannel = MethodChannel(messenger, "dev.steenbakker.flutter_ble_peripheral/ble_state")
    eventChannel = EventChannel(messenger, "dev.steenbakker.flutter_ble_peripheral/ble_event")
    methodChannel!!.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    eventChannel!!.setStreamHandler(this)
    peripheral = Peripheral()
    peripheral!!.init(applicationContext)
  }
```

When using the old pubspec, everything is working fine on both iOS and Android, however, the new pubspec style gives the same error on both iOS and Android

Comment: try `flutter clean` and then `flutter run`.

Comment: I've tried that multiple times but that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your pubspec.yaml. The correct keyword is "platforms", not "platform". So this should fix it:

```
flutter:
  plugin:
    platforms:
      ios:
        pluginClass: FlutterBlePeripheralPlugin
      android:
        package: dev.steenbakker.flutter_ble_peripheral
        pluginClass: FlutterBlePeripheralPlugin
```

Comment: Can't believe it's something that simple.. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know exactly what was wrong, but i suspect something in the android manifest to be faulty after upgrading to the new notation.

What fixed my problem was installing the dev channel of flutter using the `flutter channel dev` and then `flutter upgrade`. After the dev channel was installed I created a new project with `flutter create --org com.example --template=plugin hello`, which created a empty project with the new embedding v2 and the new pubspec notation. Then I moved all my logic from the faulty project to the newly created project.

Comment: So someone have this problem. My latest sdk flutter project still using embedding v1 instead of v2 for all the new project I created. I just dont know how to create the project with latest v2 android embedding.